# Control images wont show up in jQuery skitter slideshow plugin?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to add the image icons to my slideshow plugin, but they wont work...even though I have added the images and referenced them in the css? My path to the images folder is also correct.

Css:

http://codepad.org/7PKgOVye

Java:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.box_skitter_large').skitter({
            theme: 'clean',
            numbers_align: 'center',
            progressbar: true,
            dots: true,
            preview: true,
            controls: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What images? I don't see any in your JavaScript. BTW Java and JavaScript are two entirely different things.

Comment: I have solved it, it was due to the fact that i was using a theme which referenced the incorrect images. and thanks for the tip!